# How to perform raw SQLite query through SQLiteAsyncConnection

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-8

I am referring to http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/08/07/updated-how-to-using-sqlite-from-windows-store-apps.aspx and http://wp.qmatteoq.com/using-sqlite-in-your-windows-8-metro-style-applications/

As far as I know, `sqlite-net` doesn't have good support on foreign key. Hence, instead of creating a class to map to a table, I was using the following way for table creation.

```
    public static readonly String PROFILE_TABLE_CREATE = "create table if not exists " 
            + PROFILE_TABLE_NAME + "(" 
            + COLUMN_PROFILE_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + COLUMN_TIMESTAMP + " integer not null, "
            + COLUMN_PROFILE_NAME + " text not null, "
            + COLUMN_AGE + " integer not null, "
            + COLUMN_GENDER + " integer not null"
            + ");";

    private async void CreateDatabase()
    {
        SQLiteAsyncConnection conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(DATABASE_NAME);
        await conn.ExecuteAsync(PROFILE_TABLE_CREATE);
    }
```

---

Now, I would like to perform query. For instance, how many rows in a particular table?

I may perform `QueryAsync` as in [read column names from sqlite table windows 8 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316412/read-column-names-from-sqlite-table-windows-8-app). However, I do not have a class to map to a table.

In Java, I can perform raw query as in follow :

```
    String sql =  "select count(*) from " + tableName + " where " + HistorySQLiteOpenHelper.COLUMN_FK_TIMESTAMP + " = " + profileTimestamp;
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(sql, null);
```

How can I do so in C# Windows Store App?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get a single value, like a count, you would use `ExecuteScalarAsync`:

```cs
SQLiteAsyncConnection conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(DATABASE_NAME);
int profileCount = await conn.ExecuteScalarAsync<int>("select count(*) from " + PROFILE_TABLE);
```