# How are SQLite records updated?

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-8, windows-store-apps, sqlite-net

This code's syntax is accepted:

```
public async Task UpdateLocationAsync(SOs_Locations locations)
{
    var db = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(SQLitePath);
    await db.UpdateAsync(locations);
}
```

...but I don't grok how the SQLite engine knows which record to update when it is simply passed the class instance. Is it the case that the SQLite or SQLite-net engine peeks at the ID value and behind the scenes does a (in SQLese):

```
UPDATE SOs_Locations
Set Bla = Bla, etc.
WHERE ID = locations.Id
```

?

Comment: look at this link for an example on how to get at what you need you need to pass in your update command same theory should  work for getting a an int value if the insert was successful or not.. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/3a2ed8b9-8a2a-47ce-bd6c-11aad8bf1d87

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13679537/how-to-perform-raw-sqlite-query-with-multiple-row-result-through-sqliteasyncco

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's exactly what it does. You can check the source of the method [here](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/blob/master/src/SQLite.cs):

```
var q = string.Format ("update \"{0}\" set {1} where {2} = ? ", map.TableName, string.Join (",", (from c in cols
        select "\"" + c.Name + "\" = ? ").ToArray ()), pk.Name);
```

Of course you can always execute your own SQL if you need more control:

```
db.ExecuteAsync("UPDATE SOs_Locations Set Bla = ?, WHERE ID = ?", bla, id);
```

Comment: Great; so what I'm doing is storing the record's ID in a Tag property, and making sure that the object instance's id property is set to that value before calling UpdateAsync(). Thanks for your alternate example, too, as I will probably want to go that route on some occasions, too.